# Where would you put this functionality?

Tags: php

I have Forumtopic and Thread classes

```
class Thread
{
    public function getComments()
    {
        return array
    }
}

class Forumtopic
{
    public function post ($topicId, $comment)
    {
         SQL INSERT INTO
    }
}
```

but everytime I post something, a log should be made. I cant add this call into post() method (violate SRP). What to do then?

Comment: Another way is to 'raise a `post` event' passing the 'Forumtopic' as a subject. Then anything which wants to can watch for that event and decide what to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `Thread` and `Forumtopic` are parts of the model.

Just put you Log call somewhere in the controller, and you'll be fine.

Comment: and if I need to call them outside of controller?

Comment: You shouldn't have. It's neither the task of the view nor the model to logs things.